# Relationship between ComboBox & ListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, listbox

I have a DataSet setup like the following:

[image]

As can be seen, there's a relationship between both tables.

In my form page I have the following layout:

[image]

The combobox simply select the 'platform' and what I want to get is that the ListBox only shows records that belongs to the relationship, filtered by **plataforma_id**.

In the TableAdaptor of the Table 'SetupUrlConditions' I have set it up like the following:
[image]

When I run the app, the ListBox always shows all records instead of being filtered by the relationship. Changing the ComboBox selected item, the result is always the same.

So, Is there something missing in my code to accomplish this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Backoffice
{
    public partial class SetupRules : Form
    {
        public SetupRules()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void plataformasBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.plataformasBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.plataformasDataSet);

        }

        private void SetupRules_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.plataformasTableAdapter.Fill(this.plataformasDataSet.plataformas);


            this.setupUrlConditionsTableAdapter.Fill(this.plataformasDataSet.SetupUrlConditions);

        }

}
```

}

Comment: just because the database is configured for the relationship doesn't mean it will respond in kind on the frontend.  You need to raise the changed event for the combobox to force an update of the resultant dataset contents in the listbox.  That change will then repopulate your frontend.  As the answer below requests more of your form code, better helps us help you.

Comment: now populate both controls.  When combobox has no selection don't populate listbox.  `SelectedIndexChange` or `SelectedValueChanged` events could be used to populate listBox based on that selected value.

Comment: Hi @mvermef,  I have just done what you indicate. I have move the line: this.setupUrlConditionsTableAdapter.Fill(this.plataformasDataSet.SetupUrlConditions); within the combobox on change event and always returns all records.

Comment: no leave the TableAdapters where they are reference my answer.  Note this is like 2001 tech... I had to scratch my head alittle since I haven't actually used Forms since WPF came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void PlatformasCBO_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PlatformasCBO.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            SiteUrlLstBox.DataSource = this.platformasDataSet.SetupUrlConditions.Where(  p => p.platforma_id == (int)PlatformasCBO.SelectedValue).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Ok you made me dig for that one since I haven't done it in such a long time... 
Combobox = Platformas.  Properties to be set are DisplayMember = Plaformas, ValueMember = Id

ListBox just displaymember = condicion?...  up to you from there.

Keep in mind that something is always selected with this setup it would need to be modified to have nothing selected initially but out of scope for the question